# Using Timeout in a Script with One Command, but Multiple Hosts

Tags: bash, shell-script, ssh, array

I'm writing a script that SSH into a device, SCP a file over, names it according to the device name and then goes on to the next one. My problem is if a device is not reachable the script hangs forever. Here's my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting Backup of Ubiquiti Radios"
#cut -d' ' -f2 /usr/tmp/Script/Links.csv
#cut -d' ' -f1 /usr/tmp/Script/Links.csv
while read one two; do 
    if sshpass -p 'supersecretpassword' scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no control@"$two":/tmp/system.cfg /mnt/hgfs/Ubiquiti/$one.cfg; then
        echo $one Success!
    else
        echo $one Failed
    fi
done < /usr/tmp/Script/Links.csv
```

It works as is, but the timeout I used canceled the script as a whole, not skipping to the next device. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What kind of timeout did you use?

Comment: This is not directly related to your problem, but you should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"/mnt/hgfs/Ubiquiti/$one.cfg"` and (as shown in [Gilles Quenot’s answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/249576/80216)) `echo "$one Success!"`) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  And, yes, it would be helpful if you showed us the `timeout` usage that you’re having trouble with.

Comment: choroba I was using timeout, but for the entire script, not one device, I couldn't figure that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `timeout` command like this :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting Backup of Ubiquiti Radios"
while read one two; do 
  if timeout 60 sshpass -p 'supersecretpassword' scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no control@"$two":/tmp/system.cfg /mnt/hgfs/Ubiquiti/$one.cfg; then
    echo "$one Success!"
  else
    echo "$one Failed"
  fi
done < /usr/tmp/Script/Links.csv
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all. I am satisfied with the script and it performs exactly as intended.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Starting Backup of Ubiquiti Radios"
mkdir "/mnt/hgfs/Ubiquiti/$(date +%Y%m%d)"
while read one two; do
 if timeout 10 sshpass -p 'pass' scp -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no control@"$two":/tmp/system.cfg "/mnt/hgfs/Ubiquiti/$(date +%Y%m%d)/$one.cfg"; then
   echo "$one Success!"
 else
   echo "$one Failed"
 fi
done < /home/osboxes/Documents/Script/Links.csv
```